# Using indexes of a list passed from flask in html

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to pass a list from flask via this code:

```
package1 = ['1', 'Jackson', 'newyork','No8', '+10880275896']
render_template("index.html", package1=package1)
```

on the other side I took the parameter into an html input to use it like this:

```
< input type="text" id="name" value="{{ package1}}" >
```

Please guide me anyone: "how I can access to the indexes in the HTML code"

meant for example using index 0 of the list:

```py
package1[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the first element in the list with:

```html
<input type="text" id="name" value="{{ package1[0] }}" >
```

This will render '1' as the value of the input tag.